# Creating ~50K objects over google map through Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web

I'm designing an application which nearly displays **50K cars** over **Google Map** with some details like name, number and picture.

I would like to know what are the best practices to do that. Some have suggested to make native mobile app or desktop application but I need a **Web App** which can be run over web browser. Data will be pulled directly from server in **JSON** format.

Should I limit the data or there is some work around?

Thanks

Comment: How about using a clustering library - http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/

Comment: [Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) from the [Articles section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you're better off making clusters of the 50K data points you want to display.

Seeing 50K data points even on a 24" 1920x1080 display means you'd have ~41pixels for each which means 6x6 pixel squares for each, and they would fill all your screen.

It's obvious that you'll have a lot of overlap.

Moreover, fetching 50K data points from a server in a JSON(and you're probably going to get a big json with all of them) would mean that you'd have at least 50k x 10 x 2 = 1,000,000 bytes = 1MB for each request to pull from the server.
( 50k points x 10 bytes per floating point number with 5 decimals x 2 numbers because you have lat and long).

So if you want this to be real-time you'd probably have to make these requests each 2 seconds or so.

Also, not all of these will fit the viewport so you'd have to exclude those which are not in the viewport because they won't be displayed anyway. So the server should know what kind of display the client is using(the resolution).

I think the best way would be for you to write some clustering logic on the server-side and leave the client-side to deal with fewer data points.
(what I mean by clustering here, is that multiple points get [grouped together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddtg0.jpg) and when zooming in, they [start unfolding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMqQM.png) into separate groups)

**UPDATE**:

Also consider that as your DOM node count increases, the selectors will run slower since they'll have to search through many many nodes. But you can avoid speed problems here if  you put the markers in a layer and don't let the selectors touch that layer so they don't lose time.

**UPDATE #2**:

To send the data efficiently you can encode it with [BSON](https://github.com/jbenet/bson-cpp) and then [zip](http://www.zlib.net/) it and pass it to the client-side where you can unzip using [zlib.js](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) and use [BSON](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson) to read it.

I'm assuming you'll use C++ on the server-side, but there are [BSON implementations for  many other languages](http://bsonspec.org/#/implementation) as well.

**UPDATE #3**:

Also check the [mqtt protocol](http://mqtt.org/) which is a lightweight transport protocol. It has a Javascript implementation here [MQTT.js](https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js/)

**UPDATE #4**:
In some cases, some points might have kept their position since the last update, in which case, you wouldn't need to send their positions.

Similarly, depending on the speed of the points, and the zoom level, some points might
appear as if they're not moving at all(if you're viewing them from really far away) so you might not want to send the positions of those points each time.
So only sending those that would change position on the client-side display 
would make sense(since the other ones would appear as being static, although they're not).

Comment: ~50K cars would most probably be in a city, data can be progressively loaded, I'm wondering about the DOM.

Comment: Making a desktop application make sense?

Comment: You're welcome @WaqarAlamgir . I'd go for a web app as development would be faster and less quircky than a desktop app(where you have many platforms and harder to achieve compatibility than a web app).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, best way at such large number of object is using server-side rendering of raster.

Answer (score 0):

Get all data at once but Draw only those markers which are on the view port or near the view port. ;)

Comment: what is the best way to fetch 50K records at once